# Perl-Postgres column array and quotes

Tags: arrays, postgresql, perl

I want to populate in Perl a postgres column defined as a character array (`Tag_List[]`)

Values may contains single-quote, so when constructing the SQL string, I cannot get the right syntax to enquote these kind of values, since I already must double-enquote string values and single-enquote array type (because of the curly brackets).

I've tried to escape the single-quote (with a `$VAL =~ s/\x27/\x5c\x27/g;`) but no way :

`INSERT INTO "table-name" ("Date","Time"...,"Tag_List"[1],"Tag_List"[2],"Tag_List"[3],"Tag_List"[4],"Tag_List"[5])`
`VALUES ('2019/10/30', '14:17:59', .... ,'{"LastSuccessfulBackup-com.dellemc.avamar","2019-10-29 20:00:22 UTC"}','{"TAG1","tag value\'with quote"}',...`

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "with"`
`LIGNE 1 : ...20:00:22 UTC"}','{"TAG1","tag value\'with quote"}','{...`

Any clue ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the data type of `tag_list`? From your insert statement it looks like it would be an array of arrays.

Comment: "Tag_List" character varying(128)[]. I've tried to create a two-dimensional array with [][] but it seems to have failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert the whole array as a string:

```
CREATE TABLE arr (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   tag_list character varying(128)[]
);

INSERT INTO arr (id, tag_list) VALUES
   (1,
    '{normal_string,string with spaces,"string,with,comma","string\"with\"quote","string''with''apostrophe"}'
   );
```

This will result in entries like:

```
SELECT u.* FROM arr CROSS JOIN unnest(tag_list) AS u;
           u            
------------------------
 normal_string
 string with spaces
 string,with,comma
 string"with"quote
 string'with'apostrophe
(5 rows)
```

An alternative is to insert each array entry individually:

```
INSERT INTO arr (
   id,
   tag_list[1],
   tag_list[2],
   tag_list[3],
   tag_list[4],
   tag_list[5]
) VALUES (
   2,
   'normal_string',
   'string with spaces',
   'string,with,comma',
   'string"with"quote',
   'string''with''apostrophe'
);
```

Comment: Yes, great, it works. Many thanks. I'll now open a new subject for creating a 2-dim array and fill it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use bound parameters. (**Always** use parameter binding to send data into a database.) DBD::Pg supports array parameters by default.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $query = 'INSERT INTO "table-name" ("Date","Time"...,"Tag_List"[1],"Tag_List"[2],"Tag_List"[3],"Tag_List"[4],"Tag_List"[5]) (?,?,...,?,?,?,?,?)';
$dbh->insert($query, undef, $date, $time, ... ['TAG1',"tag value'with quote"], ...);
```